# Can any real number be expressed as the sum of a rational number with a number of the Cantor set?

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, real-numbers, cantor-set

I only ask for either a proof that this is true or a counterexample of a real number that can NOT be expressed as the sum of a rational + a number in the Cantor Set

Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear: what do you mean by Cantor set? A real number such that its "fracctional part" in base 3 consists only of digits 0 and 2?

Comment: @JoãoRocha I would think the natural interpretation is a real number in $[0,1]$ that can be represented in base-3 using only digits $0$ and $2$.  Your "fractional part" interpretation would be tiling many copies of the Cantor set, but the overall question is still logically equivalent.

Comment: The Cantor set has measure zero, and so does any translation of the Cantor set. You are in effect asking whether the real line can be covered by the union of countably many translations of a set of measure zero. The answer is no, because the measure of a countable union of sets of measure zero still has measure zero.

Comment: The comments so far are a huge hint - I suggest you think about where you find the $1$s in an arbitrary, or carefully constructed, real number.

Comment: Well, the OP asked for a proof or a counter example.  Bungo gave a third option; a proof that it's not true so .... if the OP is a stickler...  Okay, counter-example... well any normal irrational but... okay... in base 3.  r = .101001000100001.... etc.  r is not rational.  If you subtract or add any number that has only 2 or 0s as decimals in base 3 you do not get a rational number.  But all in all, I find Bungo's explanation both more satisfying and more convincing.

Comment: Would it be correct to say: a rational number is not normal, a member of the cantor set is not normal, the sum of two non-normal numbers is not normal, so any normal number is a counter-example?

Comment: So that didn't work.  Try this somewhat similar one:  *Prove or disprove that any real number $r$  can be written as $r=n+c_1 - c_2$ where $n$ is an integer and both $c_1$ and $c_2$ are in the Cantor set.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and it follows from a dimension argument. Let $C$ be the cantor set. Then your claim is that $C + \mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{R}$, i.e. that every real is a sum of an element of $C$ and a rational. We know that $\dim_{H}(C) = \frac{\log 2}{\log 3}$. But
\begin{align*}
C + \mathbb{Q} & = \{c + q : c \in C, q \in \mathbb{Q} \} \\
 & = \bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} (C + q) ,
\end{align*}
But we know since $\dim_{H}$ is translation-invariant that $\dim_{H}(C + q) = \dim_{H}(C)$, and we know that since the dimension of a countable union of sets is the supremum of the dimensions of the sets that $\dim_{H}(C + \mathbb{Q}) = \dim_{H}(\bigcup_{q \in Q} C + q) = \dim_{H}(C) = \frac{\log 2}{\log 3}$. But $\dim_{H}(\mathbb{R}) = 1$, so we know that $C + \mathbb{Q} \neq \mathbb{R}$.

EDIT: This also follows from a simpler measure argument that since Lebesgue measure is countably sub-additive, and $C$ has null Lebesgue measure, we have $\lambda(C + \mathbb{Q}) = 0$, while $\lambda(\mathbb{R}) = + \infty$. More generally, the former argument show that if you have some set $F$ where $\dim_{H}(F) < 1$, and some countable set $S$, then $F + S \neq \mathbb{R}$, where the latter is slightly more general in that we need only assume $\lambda(F) = 0$, a weaker assumption that $\dim_{H}(F) < 1$.

Comment: Thank you very much !!! :) the proof by contradiction was great, next time I'll be more specific and not only ask for a counterexample :p

Comment: I wasn't sure exactly how to show it, but I suspect that $ \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} 3^{-k}$ cannot be written as you requested, i.e. the number whose unique ternary expansion is $0$ everywhere except for on ${k! : k \in \mathbb{N}}$, where it would be $1$.

Answer (score 4):

Take any closed subset $E$ of $\mathbb R$ with empty interior, positive measure or not. Then $E + \mathbb Q \ne \mathbb R.$ Proof: Baire.

Comment: Note that unlike the measure-theory argument, this proof works completely unchanged if we replace "Cantor set" with "fat Cantor set" (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set).